# Delete table tr in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have made a function in JavaScript which automatically adds a line to a table every minute. It works fine, except that I would like to delete the second line of the table (since the first line is used for headings) if there are more than 5 lines. I tried this code:

```
if(table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length > 5){
    table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].outerHTML = "";
}
```

The problem is that when executing the second line, I get an error message saying "unknown execution error". Why does it do that? Is there any way to get around it?

In case it's important, I'm using HTA.

Comment: Works fine for me (though the second row should be index `1`). What browser gives this error? What is HTA? You should provide a full working demonstration of the issue.

Comment: Also, your headings should really go in a `<thead>` element and the rest in a `<tbody>`. Then you can simply do `table.tBodies[0].rows[0]` to get the row you want.

Comment: To delete the second row from your table, you can use `table.deleteRow(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of rows by

```
var rowCount = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
```

To delete

```
if(rowCount > 5) {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(1);  //deletes second row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
if (table.rows.length > 5) {
  table.deleteRow(1);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

(View on [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wwwbrb?editors=1010)).

- `table.rows` returns a collection of all `<tr>` elements in a table. `length` is it's property, that returns count of those elements. See [*Table rows Collection*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) at W3Schools.
- The `deleteRow` method removes the row at the specified index of a table. See [*Table deleteRow() Method*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp) at W3Schools.

You can read more about table object in [*HTML DOM Table Object*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp) at W3Schools.